# Matching non-whitespace in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, whitespace

I would like to detect strings that have non-whitespace characters in them.  Right now I am trying:

```
!Pattern.matches("\\*\\S\\*", city)
```

But it doesn't seem to be working.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  I know I could trim the string and test to see if it equals the empty string, but I would rather do it this way

Comment: You could also do the other way around with regex: `!aString.matches("\\s*")` but, as you mentioned already, `trim()` and then check the length (or `isEmpty()`) is the more logical solution, IMO.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What exactly do you think that regex matches?

Try

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "\\S" );
Matcher m = p.matcher( city );
if( m.find() )
//contains non whitespace
```

The `find` method will search for partial matches, versus a complete match. This seems to be the behavior you need.

Comment: I was hoping it would match "anything, followed by a non-whitespace character, followed by anything."

Answer (score 6):

```
city.matches(".*\\S.*")
```

or

```
Pattern nonWhitespace = Pattern.compile(".*\\S.*")
nonWhitspace.matches(city)
```

Answer (score 4):

`\S` (uppercase s) matches non-whitespace, so you don't have to negate the result of `matches`.

Also, try Matcher's method `find` instead of `Pattern.matches`.

Answer (score 1):

[Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [CharMatcher](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html) class is nice for this sort of thing:

```
boolean hasNonWhitespace = !CharMatcher.WHITESPACE.matchesAllOf(someString);
```

This matches whitespace according to the Unicode standard rather than using Java's `Character.isWhitespace()` method... `CharMatcher.JAVA_WHITESPACE` matches according to that.