# Check if line is empty in java?

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check that Java String is not all whitespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247067/how-to-check-that-java-string-is-not-all-whitespaces)

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
String random;

System.out.print("Enter your word: ");
random = kb.nextLine();

if (random.isEmpty()) {     
    System.out.println("No input detected!");                   
} else {
    System.out.println(random);
}
```

The above code doesn't account for when the user makes a space. It'll still print the blank line, when the user does a space and presses enter.

How do I fix this?

Comment: This question has been asked [so](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3824438/851811) [many](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14625265/851811) [times](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3247067/851811).

Comment: Sorry, I'll be sure to do better research next time.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can trim the whitespaces using [`String#trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) method, and then do the test: -

```
if (random.trim().isEmpty())
```

Comment: +1 trim() trims characters less than or equal to space.  This means it removes control characters which are not whitespace and doesn't remove some characters which are. ;)

Comment: FYI `for(int i=0;i<Character.MAX_CODE_POINT;i++)
            if (Character.isWhitespace(i))
                System.out.println(i);` prints `9
10
11
12
13
28
29
30
31
32
5760
6158
8192
8193
8194
8195
8196
8197
8198
8200
8201
8202
8232
8233
8287
12288
`

Comment: @PeterLawrey. o.O. That is something new to me.  Haven't come accross `MAX_CODE_POINT` constant before. What is it? Will take a look.

Comment: @PeterLawrey.. That is really a useful information I got to know today. thanks. I think, I should visit the documentations more often. :)

Comment: The maximum `int` character you can have, called a code point. > 65535. It should be `<=` not `<`

Answer (score 3):

Another solution could be trim and equals with empty string.

```
if (random.trim().equals("")){       
            System.out.println("No input detected!");                   
}
```

Comment: you would rather do "".equals(random.trim()) so that a null random doesn't throw a NPE. in that case, your solution would be more robust than rohit jains, which doesn't check for nulls.

Comment: I think then also it should give NPE on `random.trim()`

Comment: oh yeah, didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1):

another solution

```
if (random != null || !random.trim().equals(""))
   <br>System.out.println(random);
<br>else
   <br>System.out.println("No input detected!");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how Apache Commons [does it](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.3.2/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.java#StringUtils.isBlank%28java.lang.CharSequence%29):

```
public static boolean isBlank(String str) {
    int strLen;
    if (str == null || (strLen = str.length()) == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < strLen; i++) {
        if ((Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(i)) == false)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```